# In app purchase for iOS / Android - Hack Prevention

Tags: android, ios, in-app

I know that for jailbreak iOS device there is a way to get in-app purchase for free. There is in-app hack too for android.  Is there anyway to prevent this when writing app that use in-app purchase ?

thanks

Comment: Not really sure but you could check out http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html although that might be just for paid apps instead of in-app purchases.. not sure

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in addition to following all the latest Google Play/Apple licensing and security best practices you can, you need to make multiplayer interaction through your servers an intricate part of the game play and the fun.

For great examples of this, take a look at "Fun Run" or "Clash of Titans".

That being said, don't make the mistake of doing this after you've designed most of your game already. Most users (even and especially legitimate paid users) hate it when their game requires them to be online even when they're only playing it in a single player mode, and they will badmouth and down-rate your app if they suspect that you've purposefully crippled your game, or removed single player mode functionality after the fact.